What guarantees does Microsoft Graph provide for change notifications?
I am building a system that requires tracking changes of resources in MS Graph.  I'm trying to figure out if I really need to depend on delta queries or not.  To do this, I need to understand what guarantees MS Graph provides - this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.
Change notifications are being sent to Azure Event Hub, if that makes any difference.
I'm interested in the following:

Duplicate events.  If there are duplicate messages, how do you detect them? There doesn't seem to be any unique Ids on change notifications.
Missing events.  Assuming the subscription is always active, is there a chance events will be missed?
Event ordering.  I assume that there are no guarantees on ordering of messages?

Thank you.

Probably combine webhook and delta query to ensure robustness and reliability.

Create a webhook subscription of changes
Immediately after that, request all messages using the delta query
Save the delta query link

In the future, you will be notified about changes. Use it as a trigger to resubmit the delta query for all changes that have happened since the previous delta request.
It will ensure that you don't miss any changes that happen when a subscription expires or in case of sending/processing the webhook.
Regarding to the ordering. When using the delta query, messages are ordered by receivedDateTime in descending order.
I'm not familiar with Azure Event Hub, but you can receive duplicated events.
